# Youtube Iframe videoclip not loading

Tags: html

Hi ive embedded a youtube video into a html file however when i try to play it its saying vide not found?

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="width: 800px ; height: 500px"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The Error im getting when i check the console is

```
**A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.**
```

Thank you for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack overflow.

W3scools [HTML YouTube Videos](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp) has a simple guide on this. For thoroughness, see example below:

```html
 <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Hi i seen this but it didn't work any other suggestions?